# SWT window runnable on Linux but not on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swt

I added a SWT window to my project as

```
public class swtUI {
    protected Shell shell;
    protected Display display;

    public static void launch() {
        try {
            swtUI window = new swtUI();
            window.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        createContents();
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the window.
     */
    protected void createContents() {
        shell = new Shell();

        // create all controls
        blablabal
    }
}
```

and call it in `main()` as

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    swtUI.launch();
    System.out.println("\nComplete");   
}
```

No problem running on Linux.
But when I replace the linux swt.jar with maxos swt.jar and run on mac, I got exception:

```
    ***WARNING: Display must be created on main thread due to Cocoa restrictions.
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rockefeller.casanovaLab.csvCheck.CsvSuiteGUI.open(CsvSuiteGUI.java:129)
    at edu.rockefeller.casanovaLab.csvCheck.CsvSuiteGUI.launch(CsvSuiteGUI.java:119)
    at edu.rockefeller.casanovaLab.csvCheck.Program.main(Program.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
```

I am pretty new to SWT. How should I change my code to make it work on mac?

Thanks

Comment: Not much experience with SWT, but from my understanding, it's very particular about been run from within its event dispatching thread (or UI thread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems this is mentioned in [this FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#carbonapp). From the same link:

> To work around this problem you'll have to pass the -XstartOnFirstThread option to the java executable as follows:

```
java -XstartOnFirstThread -cp swt.jar:. ControlExample
```

Comment: Thanks. what is "ControlExample" at the end?

Comment: @Mavershang It's an example I took from the link. It denotes the main class of the application.